# Set string length and add " | " after 30 characters

Tags: vb.net

I'm adding 2 values from DB into combobox (concatenation for multi column combobox). Problem is that I can't insert "|" after first value at specific position, so that all combobox items would be separated evenly with a "|". I'm trying to insert "|" after 30 charachers, even If string isn't long as this. Here is my code:

```
                Using dad As New OracleDataAdapter(SQL, Myconn)
                    dad.Fill(dtb)
                End Using

               'I tried with Lset(dtb.Rows(i)(0),30) but not working - any better ideas ?

                For i As Integer = 0 To dtb.Rows.Count
                    MyCombo.Items.Add(dtb.Rows(i)(0) & " * " & dtb.Rows(i)(1))
                    i = i + 1
                Next
```

Any help appreaciated. If I wasn't clear, please ask !

EDIT:

This should be solved for ComboboxColumn in Datagrid, desired output is this:

[image]

This is image from ordinary Combobox - I created multi column combobox from DB values (Names/Surnames) using DrawItem for drawing line between data and Combobox Enter to load data. DisplayMember works (only 1 value) and no duplicating of combobox items once you select something from It.

Now I'm trying to do same with Datagridview ComboboxColumn using CellPainting event and Cell Enter events but can't do It. Last suggestions posted here have best output as this :

[image]

DisplayMember doesn't work and Items get duplicated in DatagridView's new row If you select some Item from Combobox.

Comment: That won't work because you are using a proportional font.  Each character is not the same size.  For it to work, you would need a monotype font where each character is the same size.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, what has font got to do with It ? How can I create monotype font, and where, in DB ?...Please elaborate, I don't follow you. First image is from Combobox which is not in DatagridView and I don't have any issues with It. But there I use DrawItem for drawing line between data.

Comment: The `DataGridView` has columns.  The second column always starts in the same place, so it lines up.  The `combobox` doesn't have columns so you are trying to line things up manually using spaces.  Since the font used is a proportional one, each character does not take up the same amount of space when rendered.  Look at the names _Levine_ and _Bailey_ in your picture.  They both have 6 letters but are different lengths when rendered.  If you had used a monotype font like _Courier New_, then each word would take up the same amount of space when rendered.

Comment: You will likely have to custom draw your combobox items and start the words in the second column at the same pixel location.  Codeproject.com has a [Multi-column Combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3206/Multi-Column-ComboBox) that you can use.  If you don't want to use that control, you can at least look at the source and see how they did it.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway, I allready have multicolumn combobox, you can see It from my 1st image. It works fine. This question regards to combobox in datagrid, which is harder. Im trying to host combobox control in datagrid now, but i cant figure out how to draw a line in it. This example you provided isnt for datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dtb.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim col1 As String = dtb.Rows(i).Field(Of String)(0)
    Dim col2 As String = dtb.Rows(i).Field(Of String)(1)
    col1 = If(col1.Length < 30, col1.PadRight(30) & "|", col1.Insert(30, "|"))
    col2 = If(col2.Length < 30, col2.PadRight(30) & "|", col2.Insert(30, "|"))
    MyCombo.Items.Add(col1 & " * " & col2)
Next
```

Comment: unfortunally not, this adds double "|" after 1st value and adds another one after 2nd value, and all is scrambled. But I think you're on the right path, I need to try a little bit different way.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 this seems to be doing what you want. Maybe give us a sample input and output.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, please take a look at my edited question. It's elaborated more now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
MyCombo.Items.Add(dtb.Rows(i)(0).ToString().PadRight(30) & " | * " & dtb.Rows(i)(1).ToString())
```

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
        For Each r As DataRow In dtb.Rows
            Dim col1 As String = If(r.IsNull(0), "", r.Field(Of String)(0).Trim())
            Dim col2 As String = If(r.IsNull(1), "", r.Field(Of String)(1).Trim())

            MyCombo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", col1.PadRight(30), col2.PadRight(30)))
        Next
```

Comment: Pretty odd. This should work just like Tim's answer. I do believe that `PadRight` is your answer. Experiment with it just a bit.

Comment: yes I think so too, but nothing seems to work correctly, I'm testing all I can remember.

Comment: Break it down to `MyCombo.Items.Add(dtb.Rows(i)(0).ToString().PadRight(30))` and see the results.

Comment: this doesn't help me anything - It only adds one DB value to combobox, nothing else. However, I tried with Msgbox(col1.Length), and It's allways returning me 30 - which is exact max length of my fields in DB. So I reckon strings inserted have allways length of 30, but when inserting new Item something odd happens ?

Comment: So in DB col1 is char(30)?

Comment: yes. And col2 too. I just tested If col1 data are all same length -  this way It works.

Comment: Then `MyCombo.Items.Add(dtb.Rows(i)(0).ToString() & " | " & dtb.Rows(i)(1).ToString())` should work.

Comment: yes, but It's not and I don't know why. Maybe I have something wrong in a For loop - because now I get error "There is no row at position 2". I changed my DB data to only 2 records, for testing...I forgot to mention, maybe that is cause of everything - this is a Combobox of Datagridview.

Comment: You have to remove `i = i + 1` from inside for.

Comment: nope, did this before but same problem. Also strangely, to get combobox populated with both DB values I must use  "0 To dtb.Rows.Count" and not "0 To dtb.Rows.Count -1". And even more strangely - after I click on some value and go to next row in datagrid, combobox duplicates selected item.

Comment: I have posted edited question, If you'll have time please take a look.

Comment: your code works now, text is even, but there are still issues. First of all, after you select some Item, combobox items are being duplicated. And I would like to display only first value after select, is that possible ?